# how to increase size of string array to add extra data at the end of arraylist

Tags: java, string, csv, arraylist

I am populating a CSV file and want to store in arraylist. 
In the CSV file some records have null values at the last field. If they are blank then data is populated easily. But when there is null at last field.
It throws exception :

> CSV file cannot be read : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26

There are 27 fields in csv file and exception comes at last field. Is there any way to increase size of String array for these records so I can reach 26 fields and then insert blank at 27th position?

code snippet is ::

```
String csvFile = "State.txt";
     ArrayList<StateRecord> state=new ArrayList<StateRecord>();
     SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/DD/yyyy");


BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));

String line = " ";
while ((line= br.readLine()) != null) 

 {
        lineNumber++;

String[] st=line.split("\\|");

String[] t;

StateRecord stItem = new StateRecord();
stItem.setstateISONumericId(st[0]);

stItem.setstateISOName(st[1]);

stItem.setstateISOAbbrName(st[2]);
stItem.setstateISOVeryAbbrName(st[3]);
        stItem.setstateEffectiveDate(dateFormat.parse(st[4]));
        stItem.setstateDivisionTypeCode(st[5]);
        stItem.setstateLastTransDate(dateFormat.parse(st[6]));
        stItem.setstateLastTransCode(st[7]);


}
state.add(StItem);
```

Comment: Could you show your code, it is hard to awser without it.

thanks

Comment: Could you indent your code ... thx

Comment: Please don't paste code into comments, since it's unreadable.  Just go back and edit your original question to add the code.

Comment: Main problem is that in csv file last, last field is  Null. so if there is some data in last field then fine..but in 3 records last field is empty. I mean Null. so while ((line= br.readLine()) != null) 
terminates before reading last field. thats the problem

Comment: A CSV file is text and text cannot be null. In which line is the exception happening? Is it possible that the CSV file does not contain 26 `|` in all rows? Can you minimize the CSV file to that it contains only one line which causes the problem? If so, can you add that line to your post, please?

Comment: #thomas , I have csv file with 266 records. At 237th record got exception.As at last field that is 27 is NULL.so I reaches only 26 records and then when I try to read 27th field, it throws exception.So my concern is how to handle this null.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below logic. Like wrap up your logic inside this if statement " if(line.split("\|").length>1) ". This will let you skip all the null columns

```
  while ((line= br.readLine()) != null) 

  {
      if(line.split("\\|").length>1) { // This logic will help you to skip null columns
              lineNumber++;
              String[] st=line.split("\\|");
               ---------------------------
                       your logic
               ---------------------------

 }
```